I need to show only the earliest date for a given status
Today, the table that holds the board column of the feature is showing the same status for multiple days. Since I want to create a daily evolution chart, I would like to find a way to display only the first day, that is, the day the column was changed.

Just a note, in this case I sent, they are all at the same time, but sometimes it shows different times.
I need to see one line just.

Since your representative data sample shows identical lines, you can just remove duplicates and be done. If your posted data is not representative, what is the purpose of showing it?

Instead of posting a screenshot, it is better to convert your data into copiable markdown using https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/

Bring data into powerquery with data ... from table/range.
In powerquery, click select the date column ... transform ... data type from from datetime to date

click select all the relevant columns, right click, remove duplicates
file close and load back to excel
sample code
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Changed Date", type date}}),
#"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Changed Type")
in  #"Removed Duplicates"


The issue is that this way it filters by date, and then the statuses disappear. The tip about the date was very helpful, it improved a lot, but now I need to bring the first date for each status. For example, feature 1 has 2 statuses, which are repeating multiple times. I need to show the two statuses, but only with the first date, so that the graph doesn't count them multiple times."

edit your question to provide sample input and sample desired output

after your tip, I solved this item using the "table1 = DISTINCT(status_feature)" thank you!
